# How to handle in Play! framework a form post with jsAction?

Tags: playframework, sammy.js

I'm struggling with it for some time with no results. I want data entered in a form and submitted to be rendered as a new row of a table being on the same page (without the page reload). What I currently have is an item model with several fields,
a controller with `saveItem` action:

```
public static void saveItem(@Valid SoldItem item) {...
```

, and of course the form:

```
<tr class="itemNew">
    <td>
        <input type="image" id="saveItem" name="&{'Save'}" alt="&{'Save'}" height="16" src="/public/images/001_06.png" form="itemsTable"/>
        <a href="#/cancelEdits"><image id="cancelEdits" src="/public/images/001_05.png" alt="&{'Cancel'}" title="&{'Cancel'}" height="16"></a>
    </td>

    <td>
        <div class="item">
            <input class="itemDesc" type="text" size="30" name="item.item.name" placeholder="&{'item.name'}" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <textarea class="itemDesc" rows="2" cols="30" name="item.item.description" placeholder="&{'item.description'}" ></textarea>
        </div>
    </td>
```

....

with some JavaScript:

```
    this.post('#/saveItem', function (context) {
        var item_def = new Sammy.Object();
        context.log('saveItem - params = ' + this.params);
        context.log('saveItem - form_fields = {');
        //for ( var item in this.params.keys()) {
        var items = this.params.keys(true);
        for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            context.log('item: ' + item);
            if(item.match(/^item\./)) {
                item_def[':'+ item] = this.params[item];
            }
        }
        context.log('}');
        context.log('item_def: ' + item_def);
        var action = #{jsAction @Invoices.saveItem(item_def) /};
        context.log('action: ' + action({item: item_def}));
        this.partial(action({item: item_def}));
    });
```

The latter is a `Sammy.js` fragment but this seems to be irrelevant to the case. What I get is totally *nothing*. Here is the sample of the last two log entries:

```
[Fri Jun 10 2011 01:30:51] item_def: Sammy.Object: {":item.item.name": aaa,":item.item.description": dsfsd,":item.retailPrice": dsfs,":item.rebate": sdf,":item.quantity": dsf,":item.vatRate": d,":item.notes": ds}
[Fri Jun 10 2011 01:30:51 ] action: /invoices/saveitem
```

The documentation of `jsAction` does not cover such issue, and I couldn't find any example, so please help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution I came up with is:

```
    this.post('#/saveItem', function (context) {
        var items = this.params.toHash();
        var action = #{jsAction @Invoices.saveItem() /};
        this.send($.post, action(), items)
            .then(function(contents) {
                this.swap(contents);
            });
    });
```

Some explanation I've found on the [playframework group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/tnBpdf2xBJs/discussion). When ***posting*** from a form there is no need to create full query URL. All the parameters should be sent as the post body. The above example shows use of [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org) framework (within [Play! framework](http://www.playframework.org)) and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is wrong

```
var action = #{jsAction @Invoices.saveItem(item_def) /};
```

it should be

```
var action = #{jsAction @Invoices.saveItem(item) /};
```

You are assigning `item_def` to `item` in your next line, but item doesn't exist, hence nothing being sent or outputted.

Comment: And what is `item` here? I haven't defined such variable.

Comment: `action({item: item_def}));` is saying, put the variable `item_def` into the variable `item`, and `item` is the name of the variable in your controller.